# Fallo al Actualizar WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Estoy intentando actualizar mi página de WordPress pero me da el siguiente error:

```
Actualizar WordPress
Descargando la actualización desde https://downloads.wordpress.org/release/es_ES/wordpress-6.4.3.zip…

No se ha podido verificar la identidad de wordpress-6.4.3.zip porque no se ha encontrado ninguna firma.

Descomprimiendo la actualización…

Verificando los archivos descomprimidos…

Preparando la instalación de la última versión…

Activando el modo de mantenimiento…

Copiando los archivos necesarios…

Desactivando el modo de mantenimiento…

No ha sido posible copiar el archivo.: wp-config-sample.php

Instalación fallida
```

¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: Posible problema de permisos, verifica que tus carpetas tengan los permisos correctos.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentarlo con lo siguiente:

1- Verifica los permisos de donde sea que vas a extraer los archivos.

2- Puedes ir a https://wordpress.org/download/ y bajar de ahí WP y [subirlo por FTP](https://developer.wordpress.org/advanced-administration/upgrade/upgrading/). Yo creo que esto sería lo más complejo si ya estas en un hosting.

3- Puedes [actualizar WP por CLI](https://kinsta.com/es/blog/wp-cli/) con el comando que solo bajaría WordPress sin temas, ni plugins.

```
wp core download --skip-content --force
```

En mi caso me gusta trabajar con el [CLI de WP](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/), pero pueda que tu debas aprender más sobre ello antes.

4- Prueba subiendo tu mismo el **wp-config-sample.php** a ver si eso te ayuda.